# How can I do Sentiment analysis for specific dataset?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset which contains reviews of hotels. I want to predict whether review is positive or negative.  But i don't have a dependent variable y in my dataset. 
I am tring to use NLTK and naive Bayes algorithm. Please help me to solve this problem.
Here is my code up to now.

```
Reviews = dataset.iloc[:,18]
#print(Reviews)
#Cleaning the texts
import re

import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
corpus = []
for num in range(0,10000):
  #nltk.download('stopwords')
  review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]' , ' ' , str(Reviews[num]))
  review = review.lower()
  review = review.split()
  ps = PorterStemmer()
  review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
  review = ' '.join(review)
  corpus.append(review)
print(corpus)

#Creating the Bag of Words Model
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
print(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you do not have a target class (dependent variable y) I believe that you should consider an unsupervised learning approach e.g clustering.

Comment: Something like LDA may prove helpful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have target variable than you can give try to Textblob

```
 from textblob import Textblob
 testimonial = TextBlob("today is a bad day for me!")
 print(testimonial.sentiment)
 # o/p (polarity close to 1 means positive, close to -1 means negative)
 Sentiment(polarity=-0.8749999999999998, subjectivity=0.6666666666666666)
```